# Building Emscripten Project with an IDE?

Tags: c++, c++11, emscripten

I've recently discovered Emscripten as a way of writing native code and running it in a web browser.

I'd like to work with an IDE for code completion and be able to customize the build process for Emscripten.

The only tool I've found to build Emscripten this way is with VS2010 which has very limited c++11 support so that's not desirable.

I thought of using VS2013 and writing a custom build script but I've never used VS so I'm unsure how to do that or if it's even possible.

What are people using to work with Emscripten?

Comment: You could also use [NaCl](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client) to run native code in some browsers

Comment: So that's dependant on chrome and requires a plugin that may not be on the client?

Comment: Found anything?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are aware of this. On the requirements [page](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/building_from_source/toolchain_what_is_needed.html), the following is stated:

*Visual Studio 2010 is required! Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2013 do not correctly compile Fastcomp. This issue will be fixed (eventually) when Fastcomp is migrated to use a LLVM 3.4 or later.*

Comment: Well that's good to know that VS is no longer an option. Thank you!

Comment: Wait, sorry. The plan was to use VS for code completion and the build script would call the emcc compiler. I just don't know if that's possible in VS or how to do it.